# How to write pluck/contains function without using map/reduce function?How to write .Shuffle()?

Tags: javascript, callback

Pluck function is based on map function:

```
  _.map = function(collection, iterator) {
    var result = [];

    _.each(collection,function(value,key,collection){

      result.push(iterator(value,key,collection));
    })
    return result;
  };
```

How to write below pluck function without using map function but still works the same way...? using for loop?

```
  _.pluck = function(collection, key) {
    return _.map(collection, function(item){
      return item[key];
    });
  };
var car = [{ type: "Fiat", model: "500", color: "white" }];
console.log(pluck(car, 'type')); //"Fiat"
```

Also, how to write the contains function without using reduce function:

```
_.reduce = function(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator,value);
    });
    return accumulator;
  };



  _.contains = function(collection, target) {
    return _.reduce(collection, function(wasFound, item) {
      if (wasFound) {
        return true;
      }
      return item === target;
    }, false);
  };

contains([1,2,3],3) //true
```

Lastly...how to write the shuffle function...according to underscore.js.
the shuffle function:
shuffle_.shuffle(list)

```
 Returns a shuffled copy of the list, using a version of the Fisher-Yates shuffle. 
_.shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);
=> [4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple `for` loop:

```
function pluck(arr, key) {
  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr[i][key]) out.push(arr[i][key]);
  }
  return out;
}

pluck(car, 'type');
```

And `contains`:

```
function contains(arr, key, from) {
  for (var i = from || 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === key) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

contains(arr, 2, 1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25gy4qmk/1/)

Comment: thanks it works, tho I don't think 'if' here is needed...can you please show me other two as well?

Comment: The `if` is needed to check that the object contains the key. If that check isn't done and the key isn't there the function will fail.

Comment: `shuffle` uses a `for` loop anyway [as you can see from the annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html), so I don't know why you would want the code for that.

Comment: also, how do you use for loop for .contains()?

Comment: @DanielL, what do you mean? My answer has the code for `contains` too.